# Cannot access prototype of HTML element in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am trying to fill a textarea in a window opened with `open(link_here)` (on the same domain). It works fine in all browsers except IE/Edge.

Steps to reproduce here on stackoverflow:

```
 var w = open('https://stackoverflow.com'); // example
 // (allow popups and) wait for window to be opened, then:
 let input = w.document.getElementsByClassName('f-input js-search-field')[0]    
 const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(input); // returns null on IE/Edge
```

Any workaround?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a Hierarchy access restriction. Since the element is not in the same `window` as the `Object` you are using, it doesn't have access to the object's information. You will have a somewhat similar problem if you try to append an element created by the main document and try to append it to the iframe document. When attempting this you will get a `HierarchyRequestError`.

Instead of using the main `window`'s `Object` use the iframe `window`'s `Object`:

```
var prototype = w.window.Object.getPrototypeOf(input);
console.log(prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of vanilla javascript try JQUERY which works on every browser correct so change your selector to jquery one you need to include first JQUERY at your file

Comment: Using jQuery here wouldn't matter as jQuery has no equivalent `getPrototypeOf()` method let alone a cross browser version. You would end up still having to use the native `getPrototypeOf()` method.